# Type safe list transformations

Tags: dart

I am having a heck of a time with list transformations in Dart. Since the bulk of my experience is with Typescript I will provide a working example in TS and then my solution in Dart.

Typescript with type safety from response to creation of Coin object.

```
type Entry = {
  spark: Record<string, Spark>;
};

type Spark = {
  t: number;
  p: number;
};

const coin = (entry: Entry): Coin => ({
  sparkline: Object.values(entry.spark)
    .sort((a, b) => a.t - b.t)
    .map(spark => spark.p)
});

type Coin = {
  sparkline: number[];
};
```

Dart with fragile types, confusing string transform, and no way to tell the compiler what's inside this map.

```
  Coin.fromEntry(MapEntry<String, Map> e)
      : this.sparkline = List<num>.from((List<Map>.from(e.value['spark'].values)
              ..sort((a, b) => a['t'].compareTo(b['t'])))
            .map((spark) => spark['p'].toDouble())
            .toList());
```

Is there a way to do list transformations that are type safe from response to Coin object that are easier to read?

Comment: What's the problem with `e.value['spark'].values
              ..sort((a, b) => a['t'].compareTo(b['t'])))
            .map((spark) => spark['p'].toDouble())
            .toList());` or perhaps `(e.value['spark'].values as List<String>)
              ..sort((a, b) => a['t'].compareTo(b['t'])))
            .map((spark) => spark['p'].toDouble())
            .toList());`?

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way to translate the typescript code.

```
class Entry {
  Map<String, Spark> spark;
}

class Spark {
  int t;
  double p;
}

class Coin {
  List<double> sparkline;

  Coin.fromEntry(Entry entry)
      : sparkline = (entry.spark.values.toList()
              ..sort((a, b) => a.t.compareTo(b.t)))
            .map((spark) => spark.p)
            .toList() {}
}
```

If the `Spark` is coming into your program as a JSON object/dictionary, I would recommend creating a separate de-serialization method. This way, instead of working with dynamic values all over the place, you are able to leverage the type system when operating on Spark values.